# how to make your jump forgiving in unity 2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

you know in good platform games the jump is forgiving like if you jumped and your collider isn't touching the ground after you touch the ground the player jump automatically I trayed to do it with a timer but some times the jump delays.

```
void Jump(bool isPressed)
{
    if (isPressed && Ccollider2D.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Ground")))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0f);
        rb.velocity += new Vector2(0f, jumpForce); 

    }
    else if (isPressed && Bcollider2D.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Ground")) && Ccollider2D.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Ground")) == false)
    {
        StartCoroutine(jumpWait());

    }

}

IEnumerator jumpWait()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.08f);
    if (Ccollider2D.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Ground")))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0f);
        rb.velocity += new Vector2(0f, jumpForce);
    }

}
```

what is the actual method to do it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no way for me to be sure of the function of Bcollider2D and Ccollider2D in your code, but for the timer you’d likely be better off using something like this:

```
float tryJumpTime = 0;

void Jump(bool isPressed)
{
    if ( (isPressed || tryJumpTime > Time.time) && Ccollider2D.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Ground")))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0f);
        rb.velocity += new Vector2(0f, jumpForce); 
    }
    else if (isPressed && Bcollider2D.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Ground")) && Ccollider2D.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Ground")) == false)
    {
       tryJumpTime = Time.time + 0.08f;
    }
}
```